# How to select every two / three children or sibling elements and apply styling?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass

I have a div of 10 children. I want to apply `display: 'flex'` and `flex-direction: 'row'` to every two children of the parent div. But at the moment to do so I have to further place two divs in a separate div and do styling. Is there a method or pseudo class that I don't create `class='flex-row'`. Thank you.

```
<div>
    <div class='flex-row'>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <div class='flex-row'>
        <div>C</div>
        <div>D</div>
    </div>
    <div class='flex-row'>
        <div>E</div>
        <div>F</div>
    </div>
    <div class='flex-row'>
        <div>G</div>
        <div>H</div>
    </div>
    <div class='flex-row'>
        <div>I</div>
        <div>J</div>
    </div>
</div>

.flex-row {
display: flex;
flex-direction: 'row'   
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you  mean by 'every two children' - from your HTML it looks as though you are applying flex-row to every child of the top div. Also, what is the purpose of the inserted divs (e.g.<div>A</div><div>B</div>) which don't seem to have any styling?

Comment: I am applying flex: row on two by two children. Like div A, div B. and then div C and div D. div A, div B would be on same row. div C and div D on separate new line below in row.

Comment: you are applying flex:row on every child of the parent div, div A and B are inside of the row. So.. what do you want to know? you want to apply flex-row without having to apply the class?

Answer (score 1):

try this:
`yourDivClass.nth-child(3n) {}`

this will select every third child element of the div

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i completly understood what you want, maybe this? that would apply flex and row to all direct children of "maindiv"

```css
.maindiv > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
    <div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>C</div>
        <div>D</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>E</div>
        <div>F</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>G</div>
        <div>H</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>I</div>
        <div>J</div>
    </div>
</div>
```